# Initializing Swift Optional in Class Method

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6.3.1

New at Swift and playing around with optionals and how they work.  Is there some reason you can't initialize an optional in a struct method?  If you change 'A' to be a class then this all works. Using Xcode 6.3.1.

```
struct A {
    var myString: String?

    init () {
        // do something
    }

    func getData () {
        // This next line doesn't compile correctly
        //self.myString = "This is a test"
    }    
}

var a = A()
a.myString = "Test" // This line works
```

Comment: This is not a problem of optionals. The reason is that a struct method which modifies properties must be marked as "mutating". – Lookup "Modifying Value Types from Within Instance Methods" in the Swift book!

Comment: One must admit that the Swift error message could do a slightly better job of stating the issue.